# What is the song playing in Code Geass R1 episode 24 when the black knights are ready to fire with the heavy cannon?

Tags: music, code-geass

What is the epic song that plays in the 24th episode of *Code Geass: Lelouch of the Rebellion R1* at 8:51, when the black knights are ready to fire with the heavy cannon "Super Electromagnetic Shrapnel Cannon"?

Answer (score 2):

It's **Black Knights**, the 11th track of *Code Geass - Lelouch of the Rebellion O.S.T. 2*. ([SoundCloud link](https://soundcloud.com/star-pat-460876558/code-geass-lelouch-of-the-rebellion-ost-2-11-black-knights)))